# Docker Flask App Loads Images Multiple Times

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask

My Docker Flask App is loading images multiple times. The page is very slow to load because it's making several of the same requests. I can see it in Chrome Dev Tools Networks. The app runs fine in my development environment. I'm very new to Docker.

I think it has to do with IP and port settings. I've tried several permuations of each IP/port setting with little success. Either I can't find my app at any address or it works but reloads images multiple times and is very slow.

Flask:

```
from grocery import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host ='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
ENV NAME Grocery
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

Docker Commands:

```
docker build --tag=grocery .
# this is what has worked to get to the app running 
docker run -p 5000:5000 --env-file .env grocery
```

App is then found at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

I would expect the app to run and load images only once. I'm at a loss here.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The html/css/js files are on my local machine. The images are in s3 and CloudFront.  Not sure if that would make a difference.

Edit2: Adding more code as I was able to find the issue. See my answer below.

```
@main.route('/cdn/<path:filename>')
def custom_static(filename):

    return redirect(urljoin(os.environ['CLOUDFRONT_CDN_MAIN'], filename))
```

.env file

```
CLOUDFRONT_CDN_MAIN="https://example.com"
```

Comment: If you run the sane app outside of Docker, I bet the images will still be reloaded... Docker or IP or ports isn't the problem. You should be using a static file server like nginx to cache the images

Comment: I just ran the app in my pipenv shell to confirm everything works. It seems to behave normally outside docker. I dont have any static file servers setup other than what flask has built in. Is @cricket_007 saying that I need to set one up for docker to work properly?

Comment: I guess without seeing how your app is loading the images, it's hard to tell the issue. I just find it hard to believe that docker is causing what you're seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by flask redirect and my .env file containing quotes. When running in pipenv shell my code worked fine. When running in docker, the return redirect added the quotes into the redirect and caused an infinite redirect loop.

I changed:

```
CLOUDFRONT_CDN_MAIN="https://example.com"
```

to:

```
CLOUDFRONT_CDN_MAIN=https://example.com
```

and everything works now.